# Which event belongs to "type text into textfield" using jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, checkbox, textfield

Just imagine a formular where there is a checkbox and a textfield. If someone starts typing into the textfield "bla bla bla whatever", the checkbox should tick itself. Is there a event that corresponds to the typing or do I have to use .focus ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

events which are fired on typing are:

- `onkeydown` (jQuery: `keydown`)
- `onkeyup` (jQuery: `keyup`)
- `onkeypress` (jQuery: `keypress`)

You may create an event handler to any of those to modify or influence users input.
Also be aware of `.preventDefault()` and `.stopPropagation()` functions, which prevent the default behavior for an element or suppress the event bubbling up the DOM.

References: [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/), [keydown](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/), [keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/), [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, `keyup()` event handler. See http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Answer (score 3):

If you use jQueryUI the autocomplete function has a source event which is fired on typing, ctrl+v pasting and so on. It also has the huge advantage of specifying a minimum length and keystroke delay.

jQueryUI .autocomplete() is quite versatile and not just reserved for complex ajax tasks.

```
$("input#vin").autocomplete({
  delay: 500,
  minLength: 17,
  source: function () {
    // Do your stuff here, keep in mind that you can't use $(this) inside this closure, as it is closed in of the autocomplete function. 
    decodeVinAjax(autofillVehicleDetails, $('input#vin').val());
  }
});
```