# jquery validation problem

Tags: jquery

I have a question related to jquery. Basically I want to do a very simple thing. I have a text input field. On submit, I want to display error message if the field is empty.
I have done this way:

```
errMsg = "Please write name";               
$("div#errMsg").css("background-color", "red");
 $("div#errMsg").html(errMsg);
```

and in the HTML:

```
<div id="errMsg"></div>
<strong>Name:  </strong>
<input name="name" id="name" type="text" maxlength="255" size="50" />
```

It works fine, however there is a problem. When I leave the field empty and it displays the error message, the error message does not go away without refreshing the page.
I am trying to do it so that when there is error message, and i type something in the field, it automatically remove the error without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1):

You prevent submit by returning false. E.g.

```
if($('#name').val().trim() == "")
{
    Alert('Please write name');
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the input textbox, you will want to detect changes to the text:

```
$("#name").onChange( function(event){ //Re-evaluate to see if error should be displayed} );
```

Comment: The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to <input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.

Comment: This will not fulfil the requirement:  i type something in the field, it automatically remove the error without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jquery how to detect a textboxs content has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481152/jquery-how-to-detect-a-textboxs-content-has-changed).

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a handler when the page first loads to the `#name` element's [`change` event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) like this:

```
$("#name").change(function() {
  //with .toggle(bool) we're only showing the element if the value's empty
  $("#errMsg").toggle(this.value == "").html("Please write name");
}).change(); //call it initially, in case we started invalid
```

This also involves giving the `<div>` CSS for styling, which is easier to maintain:

```
#errMsg { background-color: red; } /*could also use a class and apply that here*/
```

In your [`submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) handler there's no need (unless you change the value programmatically), but if you feel the need to run the check again, just call [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) to execute the handler again, like this:

```
$("#name").change();
```