# creating and running a client script from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a script like this an run that :(below is attemp)

```
protected void txtPassword_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        script  =  "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        script += "function showmsg(){";
        script += "$('#msg').slideDown('normal');";
        script += "$('#msg span').addClass('message');";
        script += "setTimeout('showmsg',100);";
        script += "}";
        script += "</script>";
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "ShowMessage",script);
}
```

Where is my mistake ? why there is no run ?

Comment: You have registered the script but where/when are you calling showmsg() method???

Comment: How Can run that in text_changed or textbox_blur ?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the script is now a part of the page, the function `showmsg()` needs to be called:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    showmsg();
    });
</script>
```

since you are using jQuery, this should execute the code in the `showmsg` function.

Comment: why registering code , runs in a load or click event but not in text_changed ????

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to register the script this way in code. You can simply check for the change in text of the textbox using javascript/jquery.

Since you are using jquery, the change() event does not work as in standart JavaScript when detecting change in textbox text change.

Have a look at this link where something similar was already answered.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1481155/448407

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to register the script. Just do this to handle the change event on the client side:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#<%= txtPassword.ClientID %>').change(function() {
     alert('Handler for .change() called.');
  });
});
```

You use the control's ClientID property to find it with jQuery and subscribe to change event.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It seem that you are using some jquery markup to do apply some animation, remember that with jquery you must load the Document before manipulate the DOM.

$(document).ready(function()
{

//your script

});

Answer (score 0):

seems you forgot to say that your script is a string, it shoud work this way.

```
 protected void txtPassword_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string script  =  "<script type='text/javascript'>";
            script += "function showmsg(){";
            script += "$('#msg').slideDown('normal');";
            script += "$('#msg span').addClass('message');";
            script += "setTimeout('showmsg',100);";
            script += "}";
            script += "</script>";
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "ShowMessage",script);
    }
```