# Textchange event not firng in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I've got a textbox name txtEmpcode.When it looses focus i want to show a alert message.I've written jquery for the above functionality,but its not working...

THis is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    //Raised before processing of an asynchronous postback starts and the postback request is sent to the server.
    prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    // Raised after an asynchronous postback is finished and control has been returned to the browser.
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);    
    AutoComp();//Function for autocomplete textbox        

    $("#<%=txtEmpCode.ClientID").change(function(){         
        alert("hai");
    });

});
```

Heres my asp.net textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpCode" runat="server" Width="250px" ToolTip="Enter EmployeeCode" 
AutoPostBack="True"  ontextchanged="txtEmpCode_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 3):

at the first sign you skipped %>

```
$("#<%=txtEmpCode.ClientID%>").change(function(){         
        alert("hai");
    });
```

Comment: Totally overlooked that, that could be a problem!

Answer (score 1):

When a element lost the focus you could use the .blur() function in Jquery to capture the event. Example:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#idElement').blur(function () {
           alert('i lost the focus \o/');
        });

});
```

Sorry the bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `ontextchanged="txtEmpCode_TextChanged"` from your `TextBox`.  Or remove your `change` event from your jQuery, and implement the method for `txtEmpCode_TextChanged`.  Beware, the `change` event for a textbox doesn't handle all cases.

Here is some good info on detecting changed text in a textbox: [How to detect a textbox's content has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481152/jquery-how-to-detect-a-textboxs-content-has-changed)

Comment: How are you testing to see if it is firing?  With `change`, you need to type in new text, and then tab out of the textbox to loose focus.  It doesn't fire when you're still in the textbox.

Comment: i've tested as per your comment and still not working.Im using multiview and update panel,is there any problem in this ???