# Enabling a dropdown if other forms filled in

Tags: jquery

`enter code here`i have a form with many fields. What i need is for the drop-down menu at the bottom with name of "Shipping Preference" to be disableD on default until 2 or more of the items form fields are filled in.So 2 text fields are filled in and the dropdow will be enabled. How to do? I don't have the slightest idea. Any help would be greatly appreciated. NOTE ALSO: I HAVE LIMITS ON THE FIELDS AND PLACEHOLDER. Here is the code:

```
 <SCRIPT> $("#Glass_ASTRO_165WNT").on('change', function() {
       this.value = (!Number(this.value)) ? '' : Math.max(100, Math.min(999999, Number(this.value)));
        });

    //With reference to http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html
    // 1. Handle placeholders (in non-HTML5 compliant browsers).
    if(!supports_input_placeholder()) {
        $('[placeholder]').focus(function () {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                input.val('');
                input.removeClass('placeholder');
            }
        }).blur(function () {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                input.addClass('placeholder');
                input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
            }
        }).blur();

        //2. Prevent placeholder values being submitted to form's action script
        $('[placeholder]').eq(0).closest('form').submit(function () {
            $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function () {
                var input = $(this);
                if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                    input.val('');
                }


               });
            });
        }
    });</SCRIPT>

    <form name="amada" method="post" action="review.php"onSubmit="return validate.check(this)">

                  <div class="side1">
                  <article>
                        <h2>Silver Name Badges</h2>
                        <p class="subDetails">Min. Qty: 100 pcs <br>
                          Lead Time: 3 Weeks<br>
                        <img src="web-pics/name_badge.png" width="200" height="200" alt="badge" /><br>

                         Quantity:
                    <input type="text" default=min=100 placeholder="none" name="Silver_Name_Badges" id="Silver_Name_Badges" maxlength="10" style="width:50px" tabindex=1  >

                    </p>
                </article>


 <td valign="top"><select name="Ship_Preference" id="Ship_Preference" tabindex=20 >
       <option value="Partial Shipment">Partial Shipment</option>
       <option value="When All Items Ready">Ship When All Items Ready</option>
       </select></td>
 <td valign="top"><select name="Ship_Preference" id="Ship_Preference" tabindex=20 >
       <option value="Partial Shipment">Partial Shipment</option>
       <option value="When All Items Ready">Ship When All Items Ready</option>
       </select></td>
```

Comment: ... That's too much HTML/JS to think about. Narrow down your usecase to a [Small, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) that shows what you need and what doesn't work. Ideally, provide a working jsfiddle (or equivalent) as well.

Comment: I understand. So you don't have any suggestions in the mean time? I WILL RE-ASK.

Comment: ok i trimmed it a bit. Help please.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to fire an event whenever the contents of your input elements change. When the event fires, you can check for the number of inputs elements in your form that are populated (or put another way, return a non-empty `value` attribute). Like so:

```
// Listen for 'input' events on all elements (that are not buttons)
// within the form named 'amada'
$("form[name='amada'] input[type!='button']").on("input", function(){
    // Count the number of inputs within this form that are not populated
    if($("form[name='amada"] input[value!=''][type!='button']").length >= 2){
        // If at least 2 populated inputs, enable the "Ship_Preference" select box
        $("select[name='Ship_Preference']").removeAttr("disabled");
    }else{
        // Otherwise, disable it.
        $("select[name='Ship_Preference']").attr("disabled", "disabled);
    }
})
```

Note the `type!="button"` filter will remove buttons from the selection. Remove this for simplicity if this is not relevant for your code.

Also note that the "input" event (which I stole from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9955724/877472)) will fire whenever a character is inserted, as opposed to the "change" event which will only figure when the input box loses focus. I assume this is the desired behaviour, however you can try either to see which you prefer.

Hope that helps.