# jquery cascaded focus and change function not working with textfield

Tags: jquery

Help! Function below is working with the dropdown (rubriekskeuze) but not with the textfield (plaatsnaam).

```
$("#rubriekskeuze,#plaatsnaam").focus(function () {
    //Opslaan huidige waarde
    if (this.id == 'plaatsnaam'){var originele_plaatsnaam = this.value;}else {var originele_rubriek = this.value;}
   }).change(function() {alert('plaa');
        if (this.id == 'rubriekskeuze' && vraag_categorieupdate_gesteld == 0){
            var vraag_update_rub = confirm("Weet u zeker dat u de rubriek wilt wijzigen, bij wijzigen komen de nu ingevulde kenmerken te vervallen en moeten deze opnieuw ingevuld worden voor de nieuwe rubriek");
        }
        if (vraag_categorieupdate_gesteld == 1 || vraag_update_rub){
            alert('dd');
        }
   });
```

Comment: Please generate a jsFiddle so we have some HTML markup to go along with your function.

Comment: It's also not quite clear what "isn't working" about the function. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Or even which of the 2 functions declared isn't working..

Comment: ".change" will not fire till you have left the textbox, try and use a `.keyup` for the textbox instead of `.change` if you need to have the function fire everytime a key his used.

Comment: if i change the drop down rubriekskeuze the alert 'plaa' executes, if i change the textfield plaatsnaam the alert 'plaa' doesn't execute (after i leave the textfield)

Comment: jsFiddle is a bit dificult because of the size of the page

Comment: Change event fires when you exit textfield. For detecting input see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481152/jquery-how-to-detect-a-textboxs-content-has-changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! It didn't work because of the autocomplete in the textfield...