# live() not working with change function

Tags: jquery

Hi friend following is my code

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.text').live('change',function(){
        var a = $(this).val();
        alert(a);
        })
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input name="" type="text" class="text"/>
```

I am new on jQuery i want to fetch input's value on change 
The value is dynamicly change again and again

Please help me guys

Comment: Which version of JQuery are you using ? `.live()` - **version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9**.

Comment: @kamal- Which jQuery version you are using?

Comment: Change `live` with `on`

Comment: It should work for **1.7.2**, [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hqu8/).

Comment: replace `live` with `delegate` or `on`

Comment: Please confirm, you have included jquery library

Comment: okay ... As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated.

You should use `on()`

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.text').on('change',function(){
        var a = $(this).val();
        alert(a);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For textbox, use `input` instead of `change`

```
$('.text').live('input',function(){
        var a = $(this).val();
        alert(a);
        })
});
```

Check this [**SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9955724/1671639) about On input change event.

> **BTW:** You should think of moving to latest version of jQuery and replace `.live()` with `.on()`

Answer (score 1):

The **.live() method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and has been removed in 1.9**. We recommend upgrading code to use the .on() method instead.**[jQuery Core 1.9 Upgrade Guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed)**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.text').on('change',function(){
        var a = $(this).val();
        alert(a);
        })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **on** or **click**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.text').click('change',function(){
        var a = $(this).val();
        alert(a);
        })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

{Function: "***ON()***"} {Event: "***input***"} {Works with ***ALL Form fields*** and ***HTML5*** ***"contenteditable"***}

As other user pointed out the live() function is long depreciated, however I would like to point out the true way of using on() function to get the same effect as live() and help StackOverflow users to get a better grasp of the event with a misleading name "***input***" [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

The difference is that the live() would target all elements of sort, whilst on() / bind (), targeting current affected element only, which makes it much more efficient, light and fast.

The right solution, however is not ***just*** on() or bind() as others are pointing out.
Just using on() event will "bubble up" and will not fire until you focus away from the element. The trick is in using "***input***" as a shorthand event, whilst targeting the element right after it. 
The good news is that same "***input***" event works not just on all form fields, but also on html "contenteditable" content too ;)

Full example is in the snippet below.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('body').on('input','.text',function(){
        var a = $(this).val();
        alert(a);
    });
});
```

```css
.text{
   display:block;
   width:50%;
   height:25px;
   margin:0;
   border:1px soid silver;
   background:silver;
   line-height:25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="" type="text" class="text" placeholder="Type e.g. 123"/>
<hr>
<select name="select" class="text">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
</select>
<hr>
<textarea class="text"  placeholder="Type e.g. 123"></textarea>
<hr>
<div contenteditable="true" class="text">Type e.g. 123</div>
```