# Rails form not submitting on change with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm working on a little todo list app with ruby on rails and I'd like to submit a form via ajax when a checkbox is selected. I've been following [this guide](http://trevorturk.com/2010/08/24/easy-ajax-forms-with-rails-3-and-jquery/) to try and do this.

Changing the checkbox didn't submit the form though, so I searched on SO for similar questions and made some updates to my code.

1. Using [on() instead of live()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395786/live-not-working-with-change-function)
2. Submitting the [closest form instead of form.first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418076/is-there-a-better-jquery-solution-to-this-form-submit) since I have a list of these forms on the same page

It still won't submit though. I have a feeling it's not watching '.submittable' correctly because I can't even get an alert to flash when a checkbox is clicked.

Any pointers? Have I forgotten something? Thanks.

**index.html.erb**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>Task Description</th>
    <th width="15%">Days Left</th>
    <th width="15%">Completed?</th>
  </tr>
  <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= task.description %></td>
    <td><%= task.days_remaining %> days left</td>
    <td><%= form_for task, remote: true  do |f| %>
        <%= f.check_box 'completed', id: "task-#{task.id}", class: 'submittable' %>
    <% end %>
        </td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

**application.js**

```
$('.submittable').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

**update.js.erb**

```
<% if @task.updated? %>
   $('#task-' +<%= @task.id %>).prepend("Yes");
<% else %>
   $('#task-' +<%= @task.id %>).prepend("<div class='alert alert-error'><%= flash[:error] %></div>");
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't seem to be wrapped in a call to `$(document).ready()`, so jQuery is probably trying to bind the event before your checkbox loads. Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.submittable').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
  });
});
```

Comment: Ah I really did forget something important. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait until the dom is loads

```
$(function(){
 $('.submittable').on('change', function() {
   $(this).closest('form').submit();
 });
});
```

then make sure in your controller update action

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @object.update(object_params)
    .
    .
    format.js
  else
   .
   .
  end
end
```

see this [episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised?view=comments) of railscasts he is explaining what you want to do

Comment: Sweet, I'll checkout the episode