# Changing price based on quantity

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic table with products, prices, and quantity. I want to change the price when the quantity is changed. here is my XHTML table

```
<table>
    <caption>Checkout Time!</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align="right">
                <input type="button" value="Checkout!" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="description">Folger's Gourmet Instant Coffee 24 count box.</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="price" readonly value="12.50" class="readonly" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="quantity" value="1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="total" readonly value="12.50" class="readonly" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I just want to use JQuery. Can someone help?

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481152/jquery-how-to-detect-a-textboxs-content-has-changed Please refer the link and inside the loop calculate the price*quantity value and display it in total Input textbox

Comment: var price=12.50;
$("#quantity").on("change",function(){
    quantity=$(this).val();
    total=price*quantity;
    $("#total").html(total_price);

}) didnt work. using jquery

Comment: Try keyup event as suggested by Sergio or try using val().$("#total").html(total_price) should be $("#total").val(total)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#quantity').on('keyup',function(){
    var tot = $('#price').val() * this.value;
    $('#total').val(tot);
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aC7jh/)

Comment: works perfect, how did you know what version of JQuery I was using, and how did you make it work with a smaller code? I am only a few weeks into JQuery,JSON, and Javascript

Comment: @user2807515, I just guessed I suppose :) Happy I could help! What do you mean with smaller code btw? you did not post any jQuery code...

Comment: i did, you must of not seen it. yall are true geniuses. How long does it take to get all of this "down-pat"?

Comment: @user2807515, you are "only a few weeks into JQuery", I am a bit more. It gets faster with practise ;)

Comment: Sergio, thanks for your help. I love this site, and the people willing to help. Great stuff.

Comment: How do you keep track of large price table..?

Comment: @User57 not sure of what you mean, can you explain better or post a new question with your specific scenario?

Comment: I tried to mean is that the solution you provide works for single item, and if i have multiple items where i tried to change quantity in multiple place it's only changed in one place not dynamically

Comment: @User57 if you have several `total` to fill, just use the same logic with a `forEach` loop around, keep in mind IDs are unique, so you don't use `#total` more than once. Maybe classes or different IDs.

Comment: @Sergio Can we achieve this in drop down, I mean if i have more then one drop down.

Comment: @SanjayGohil sure just use something like `$('#selectID').on('change'` instead.