# input field "onchange" event jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<input type="text" id="myinput" name="myinput" value="" />
```

how do i use jquery to detect the "onchange" event of the input field.I tried everything but nothing seems to fire it.

```
$("#myinput").bind("onchange",alert("test"));
$("#myinput").change(alert("test"));
```

im using jquery 2.03.Its the "onchange" aka once the user finishes typing then fire event.Not fire after each letter changed, because im getting json from the server and it would cause a tremendous load if it where to call on each letter change.

as paul said this is the solution i guess..thx alot

http://jsfiddle.net/kerc6/5/

Comment: Possible duplicat [Jquery: how to detect a textbox's content has changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481152/jquery-how-to-detect-a-textboxs-content-has-changed)

Comment: It should definitely work. Check in fiddle **(http://jsfiddle.net/kerc6/1/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect it to fire on each keypress then you are wrong. It will automatically fire when the focus is out of the element.

It occurs instantly only for elements like `radio-button`, `checkbox`.

For your specific purpose define jquery event `input` as follows:

```
$("input").on('input', function(){alert(1)});
```

***N.B. this works only for textual input elements for instant change detection. Most importantly, it detects any type of change i.e. through either `keyboard` or `mouse`***

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kerc6/)**

Answer (score 3):

Use the `.on()` method, create a *function handler* and do stuff inside.

```
jQuery(function( $ ){ // DOM is now ready

    $("#myinput").on("input", function(){ // or use "change" if you need
      // DO SOMETHING
    });

});
```

The other way:

```
function inputChangeStuff(){
    // DO SOMETHING
}

jQuery(function( $ ){ // DOM is now ready    
    $("#myinput").on("input", inputChangeStuff);     
});
```

Comment: those dont do nothing, im using 2.03, once i change a letter it fires but i want onchange event.

Comment: @Aflred did you read my answer? You probably missed the part `// or use "change" if you need` And how does the accepted answer differs from mine?

Comment: calm down i didnt read that my mystake.Sorry i upvoted ur answer.

Answer (score 1):

By using keyup down you can also track it:

```
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myinput").keydown(function(){
    $("#myinput").css("background-color","yellow");
   });
   $("#myinput").keyup(function(){
    $("#myinput").css("background-color","pink");
   });
 });
</script>
```