# Input field not editable after typing into it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple input field like so:

```
<input type="edit" name="search" placeholder="Start Searching..." id="sb">
```

and it was working fine for test purposes until I had to put in some JavaScript to make it do stuff. Now it works but after typing in it for awhile and it loses focus, I can't click back into it.

The JavaScript that I have detects when there is change in the text in the input field and when there is, it does stuff. Using this [How to detect a textbox's content has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481152/how-to-detect-a-textboxs-content-has-changed)

```
jQuery('#sb').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
    // do your stuff
});
```

This JavaScript renders a bunch of elements to the page directly below the search bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This JavaScript renders a bunch of elements to the page directly below the search bar.

This was the key; once I typed this, I knew what was going on.

[image]

as shown by the white rectangle, this was the area that was overlapping the search bar. This was the div that held what was being rendered by the JavaScript. I was able to type in it before it was rendered because it didn't exist and I couldn't type in it afterwards because the stuff rendered was "on top of it". So I just had to add to quick lines of CSS and it fixed the problem.

```
#sb { z-index: 0; }
#results { z-index: -999; }
```

where `#sb` is the id for the input field and `#results` is the id for the div below it being rendered by my JavaScript.