# jQuery autocomplete, on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-events

I am trying to call a function every time an autocomplete search is changed, either by key press or by clicking one of the options of the autocomplete.
Key press works fine like this...

```
 $('#searchScenario').on('keyup change', function () {
 //event
 }
```

But this won't work when I click on one of the autocomplete options.

Here is my autocomplete initialization.

```
 scenarioSearch = $('#searchScenario').autocomplete({
        source: scenarioTags,
        minLength: 0
    }).focus(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete('search', $(this).val());
    });
```

I have attempted other methods such as this...

```
(function () {  
var scenarioSearch = $("#searchScenario").autocomplete({ 
  change: function() {
      alert('changed');
  }
  });
  scenarioSearch .autocomplete('option','change').call(scenarioSearch );
  });
```

But it only triggers when the box loses focus.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's no one-size-fit-all autocomplete event for what you describe. Try assigning the same handler to the [non-widget `input` event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481152) and [the widget's `select` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not at my box but can you try it using :

```
select:function() {
      alert('changed');
  }
```

Or

```
.select()
```