# jQuery removeAttr or prop not working on submitButtons?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hy there,
I've got a little problem with my formhandling here.
I try to block the submit Button (ID:#submitForm) until any field in the formular has been changed.
Here's my jQuery Code :

```
// block submit until change
$('#submitForm').prop('disabled', true);
$(':input').change(function() {
    $('#submitForm').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

And in the site :

```
<input id="submitForm" type="submit" value="Send Form">
```

If the User changes any of the other Inputfields the Submit should be enabled to post the changes, a simple alert"MSG" does well but not the release of the disabled property.

Thanks a lot, 
DR

Comment: Seems to working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/a99c15mf/). Did you wrap it document ready event?

Comment: The change event on the inputs will be fired just if they lose focus. Use `input` instead. http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/5b3me4d8/1/

Comment: Jip, it's wrapped in document.ready.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect a textbox's content has changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481152/how-to-detect-a-textboxs-content-has-changed)

Comment: That should be fine, so the problem must be in code that you haven't shown. Side note: Even if the submit button is disabled, some browsers will submit some forms (typically those with just one input[type=text] in them) if the user presses Enter in the text field, so you have to handle the `submit` event on the form as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but keyup doesn't work either.

Comment: O.K. the ID is unique but when I change the type="submit" into type="button" everything is working fine - but I can't figure out the problem... can this perhaps get in conflict with jquery.validation Plugin ?

Comment: Your problem lies somewhere else then.

Comment: @darthrox: Perhaps you could create a Stack Snippet demonstrating the problem and put it in the question. For those, I usually use a form like this: `<form action="http://google.com/search" target="_blank"><input type="text" name="q" value="kittens"><input type="submit" id="submitForm" value="Send Form"></form>` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks for all your support** and sorry for stealing your time - the problem was the **simultaneous use of jQuery UI** (which sets additional options to the buttons, but I didn't tell you).

I solved the problem now with a mixture of the given solutions :

```
// set the form(ID) submit to the button(ID) 
$("#ID_OF_THE_BUTTON").click(function() {
    $("#ID_OF_THE_FORM").submit();
});
// set submit button(s)
$("#ID_OF_THE_BUTTON").button();
// block submit until change
$("#ID_OF_THE_BUTTON" ).button("disable");
$(":input").on("input change paste", function() {
        $("#ID_OF_THE_BUTTON").button("enable");
});
```

..and the button:

```
<button id="ID_OF_THE_BUTTON">User eintragen</button>
```

Now the submitting of the form blocked until a change in any of the given form-elements is done.