# How to remove all spaces when pasting using jQuery or JavaScript instantly?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

When a user pastes some text into a field I want to be able to remove all spaces instantly.

```
<input type="text" class="white-space-is-dead" value="dor  on" />

$('.white-space-is-dead').change(function() {   
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g,""));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U3CRg/22/

This code from another example works. But doesn't update until a user clicks on something besides the textbox. I am using MVC with jQuery/JavaScript.

Comment: Just want to quick point out java and javascript are two different languages that are completely unrelated. (other then similarity in name). This is javascript.

Comment: That was a typo sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Switch the event `change` for `input`, which will trigger whenever something is inputted into the field, even if text is being pasted.

```
$('.white-space-is-dead').on('input', function() {   
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g,""));
});
```

Take a look at [jQuery Events](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/) to understand better what options you have.

**Edit:** updated the answer based on OP's comment and what I found on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9955724/2752041).

Comment: This works if the user keeps typing. But I want it to happen during the paste action or right after.

Comment: that seems to do the job but I am wondering now if older browsers will support the paste event.

Comment: As long as they support your jQuery version, I believe you won't have any problems with that.

Comment: @Bob also, if it's really **really** important to not have any spaces in the inputted text, you should consider server-side validating and/or replacing spaces.

Comment: I am trying to remove the spaces, blocking the space-bar key works for regular input but when the user pastes in spaces I need a to remove them. Which your answer does cover but I feel as IE8 wont like it.I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: So @Bob, have you tested it on IE8 yet?

Comment: actually I went a different direction with the input. Took the text on the form trimmed it and set that to another variable to submit. As for IE8 for some reason I was getting an infinite loop may of been do to other code as well.

Answer (score 1):

The regex wasnt doing what you wanted. This works but does not fire until the text input loses focus.

```js
$('.white-space-is-dead').change(function() {   
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/ /g,''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="white-space-is-dead" value="dor  on" />
```