# How to make type sensing features in web chat application by asp.net by c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, angularjs

we have a web chat application and we wants to add type sensing features by asp.net c#. it is a multi user chat module where we need to show that a user has started writing or typing in the chat text area like any others famous chat web sites.

Any sort of idea is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Just send a message to the server on text box text changed events. Then send a keyword to the other clients as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. can you please describe the elaborate situation to get the clear idea. also we need to show the person name who is typing at the moment to the others client UI. @JBlaz

Comment: in order to help you more fully you would need to post the scheme you are using in this web application.

Comment: we are in  a chat system which has four section, 1st is for group list 2nd is having group member list and 3rd is for chat messages section and the 4th is for writing area i.e. the text area. now if anybody is typing on the text area then we need to show the persons name , that he or she is typing. here entire operation is done via client side code. two handlers is working here. now please suggest what to do? @JBlaz

Comment: Is this client talking to a server? Did you write the server? I don't really care what it looks like I care how it was written.

Comment: No the entire code snippet is written in Client side, here a interval is running for 5000 ms and then it fires one by one. so we need to be only in client side. @JBlaz

Comment: Then I would use the event http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481152/how-to-detect-a-textboxs-content-has-changed and then send text to the other clients with a keyword like <EDITING-##USERNAME##> (or something like that) then when each client gets that message a UI textblock says "USERNAME is typing...".

Comment: Thank you for the Idea,  please suggest us how to send data or text from one client to another client. so that we can get every user who got the text. @JBlaz

Comment: Just send it like you would a message the user typed in but when the text is received only display it if it doesn't contain the key words.