# on change function in jquery for textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have series of textboxes i want on change function at the last textbox.i have tired as follows,

```
<div id="filterMeasurement" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 filterControls" style="display: none;">
    <h4>Measurements in (mm)</h4>
    <div class="mea-bx">
        <h5>Length </h5>
        <div>
            <input name="txtLengthFrom" type="text" id="txtLengthFrom" class="textSmLeft" placeholder="from" />
            <input name="txtLengthTo" type="text" id="txtLengthTo" class="textSmRight" placeholder="to" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mea-bx">
        <h5>Width </h5>
        <div>
            <input name="txtWidthFrom" type="text" id="txtWidthFrom" class="textSmLeft" placeholder="from" />
            <input name="txtWidthTo" type="text" id="txtWidthTo" class="textSmRight" placeholder="to" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mea-bx">
        <h5>Height </h5>
        <div>
            <input name="txtHeightFrom" type="text" id="txtHeightFrom" class="textSmLeft" placeholder="from" />
            <input name="txtHeightTo" type="text" id="txtHeightTo" class="textSmRight" placeholder="to" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#filterMeasurement").find('input[type=text]').change(function () {
    var lengthfrom = $("#txtLengthFrom").val();
    var lengthto = $("#txtLengthTo").val();
    var widthfrom = $("#txtWidthFrom").val();
    var widthto = $("#txtWidthTo").val();
    var heightfrom = $("#txtHeightFrom").val();
    var heightto = $("#txtHeightTo").val();
    if (lengthfrom != '' && lengthto != '' && widthfrom != '' && widthto != '' && heightfrom != '' && heightto != '') {
        UpdateGrid();
    }
    else {alert("Fill all the fields")}
});
```

Here for each textbox on change throwing alert in else block.How can i get alert only on last textbox on change by checking all textboxes as mandatory?

Can anyone please help me out??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.find('input[type=text]:last')`

Comment: I think this one will usefull for you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481152/how-to-detect-a-textboxs-content-has-changed

Comment: With `style="display: none;"` at `html` `alert()` would be called where no user input ?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$("#filterMeasurement").find('input[type=text]:last')
```

► `.last()` :method returns the last element of the selected elements.

**OR**

```
$("#filterMeasurement").find('input[type=text]').last()
```

► `:last` : selector selects the last element.

**OR**

```
$("#filterMeasurement").find('input[type=text]:last-child')
```

►  `:last-child` :can match more than one: one for each parent

Answer (score 0):

> How can i get alert only on last textbox on change by checking all
>   textboxes as mandatory?

Try removing `style="display: none;"` from `#filterMeasurement"` element at `html` to allow user to input text ? Not certain how `.change()` handler could call `alert()` if user not able to input text to element not appear to rendered in document ?

You could use `$.grep()` to check if `input` elements having `id` beginning with `txt` and having `value` `.length` is equal to or equal less 1 to `input` `.length` ; call `alert()` at `input` `.length - 1` ; call `UpdateGrid()` at `input` `.length` equal to `input` elements having `value`

```js
var inputs = $("[id^=txt]");

function UpdateGrid() {
  alert("complete")
}

$("#filterMeasurement").find("input[type=text]").change(function () {
    var res = $.grep(inputs, function(el) {
      return el.value.length > 0 && !/^\s+$/.test(el.value)
    });
  
    if (res.length === inputs.length) {
      UpdateGrid();
    }
    else {
      // get alert only on last textbox on change 
      // by checking all textboxes as mandatory
      // if any input elements do not have value 
      // then alert("Fill all the fields") 
      //if (res.length === inputs.length - 1) {
         alert("Fill all the fields")
      //}
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="filterMeasurement" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 filterControls">
    <h4>Measurements in (mm)</h4>
    <div class="mea-bx">
        <h5>Length </h5>
        <div>
            <input name="txtLengthFrom" type="text" id="txtLengthFrom" class="textSmLeft" placeholder="from" />
            <input name="txtLengthTo" type="text" id="txtLengthTo" class="textSmRight" placeholder="to" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mea-bx">
        <h5>Width </h5>
        <div>
            <input name="txtWidthFrom" type="text" id="txtWidthFrom" class="textSmLeft" placeholder="from" />
            <input name="txtWidthTo" type="text" id="txtWidthTo" class="textSmRight" placeholder="to" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mea-bx">
        <h5>Height </h5>
        <div>
            <input name="txtHeightFrom" type="text" id="txtHeightFrom" class="textSmLeft" placeholder="from" />
            <input name="txtHeightTo" type="text" id="txtHeightTo" class="textSmRight" placeholder="to" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want a small change over here,have to check one or more textboxes is empty.but here it is checking only one textbox

Comment: @Janani _" want a small change over here,have to check one or more textboxes is empty.but here it is checking only one textbox"_ Not certain interpret correctly ? What is requirement ? `alert()` if any `input` elements do not have value , or if five of six `input` elements have value ?

Comment: if any input elements do not have value then  alert("Fill all the fields")

Comment: @Janani _"if any input elements do not have value then alert("Fill all the fields") "_ You can comment `if` condition within `else` ; see updated post